# How can I have multiple Business Objects on different pages in a single mrt file and display it in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, object, stimulsoft

I've created a print file with the Stimulsoft Reports program. Now my question is, can I use multiple Business Objects in this program and each of them can be displayed on separate pages, like Excel, which can have multiple sheets in a file And those sheets have different data.

If I can do it, How do I address it in C# to get the same page with the Business Object that I specify?

This is the code that looks like a file and a Business Object:

```
try
{
       var mainReport = new StiReport();

       var details = new List<Details>();

       foreach (var item in Items)
       {
                details.Add(new Details
                {
                    CarName = item.CarName,
                });
       }

       mainReport.Load(CurrentDirectory() + @"\Rp.dll");
       mainReport.RegBusinessObject("Print", details);
       mainReport.Show();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
       MessageUtility.ErrorAlert(ex.GetOriginalException().Message);
 }
```

Overall the result I want is single mrt file with different Business Objects on different pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading the report you can access the report **Pages**. Use **Enabled** property of page.

```
mainReport.Pages[0].Enabled = false;
mainReport.Pages["PageName"].Enabled = false;
```